# Chakra UI color mode in default props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chakra-ui

I'm trying to extend my theme (modify default component) and pass my new default props to the Input component. I need focusBorderColor to change by current color mode. I tried to pass a function to defaultProps parameter but this broke all styles on my Input component:

```
const theme = extendTheme({
  components: {
    Input: {
      defaultProps: props => ({
        variant: 'filled',
        focusBorderColor: props.colorMode === 'light' ? 'gray.200' : 'gray.600',
      }),
    },
  },
})
```

I also tried to style my component by baseStyle property and this works, but all default base styles are overwritten by passing a function to it. I need to add property to baseStyle and preserve default baseStyles (only extend but with color mode).

```
const theme = extendTheme({
  components: {
    Input: {
      baseStyle: props => ({
        field: {
          width: props.colorMode === 'dark' ? '50%' : '80%',
        },
      }),
    },
  },
})
```

Is there any way how to pass colorMode to default props? Or is there any way how to properly extend baseStyle with function declaration without losing default baseStyles?

Answer (score 1):

`defaultProps` can only have the following keys: `variant`, `size`, and `colorScheme`.

To change the `borderColor` when the `Input` is focused you can do

```
const theme = extendTheme({
  components: {
    Input: {
      variants: {
        filled: (props) => ({ // Notice "props" here
          field: {
            _focusVisible: {
              bg: "transparent",
              // mode is an alternative to props.colorMode === x ? y
              borderColor: mode("blue", "purple")(props)
            }
          }
        })
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Full code: https://codesandbox.io/s/chakra-ui-focus-bordercolor-muw9cv?file=/src/index.tsx

Chakra-UI's [default theme](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/theme) variants will override your `baseStyle`. You can see their default styles [here](https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/blob/main/packages/theme/src/components/input.ts) or you can use [`useMultiStyleConfig`](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/component-style#usemultistyleconfig-api) to see the styles of your `Input` component. So if the `filled` variant and other variants you want to use have a value for `borderColor` set in focus mode (set by Chakra-UI's default theme), you'll have to override this property inside the variant like in the example above.